# Переворачивание таблицы PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Да такие вопросы задавались но тут у меня не очень типичное переворачивание.
Имеется таблица.

```
CREATE TABLE #listmo  (id INT IDENTITY (1, 1), code_mo CHAR(6), nam_mok VARCHAR(254), column_mo varchar(4))

id  code_mo nam_mok                             column_mo
1   555508  БУЗОО "КОБ ИМ. В.П. ВЫХОДЦЕВА"      mo1
2   557001  ООО "ФРЕЗЕНИУС МЕДИКАЛ КЕА ОМСК"    mo2
```

Нужно привести к виду в идеале:

```
header              mo1                             mo2
Мед. организация    БУЗОО "КОБ ИМ. В.П. ВЫХОДЦЕВА"  ООО "ФРЕЗЕНИУС МЕДИКАЛ КЕА"
```

или хотябы коды:

```
header              mo1     mo2
Мед. организация    555508  557001
```

чтобы потом можно было поставить название UPDATE-ом

Так как в PIVOT агрегатные функции только (SUM, COUNT, MAX, MIN, AVG) то у меня не хватает соображалки чтобы через эти функции реализовать.

Comment: В исходных данных отсутствует то, что показано в желаемом выводе в поле `header`. Задача нерешаема.

Comment: @Akina хорошо можно без `header`, мне в данном случае неважно какие поля будут до полей `moX`. Будет ли это самописный select 'мед. организация' или вообще без него, или просто номер строки.

Comment: max(nam_mok) отлично даст нужное название. для чего именно вам не хватает агрегатных функций ?

Comment: @Mike тем что они подходят только для числовых значений. с nam_mok не прокатило, прокатило с code_mo, буду от этого отталкиваться, спасибо

Comment: Нет, это не так, max отлично работает со строками. Так что если "не прокатило" сообщите что именно пробовали и что оно вам  сказало

Comment: @Mike у меня sql server ругается, возможно это потому что у нас старая версия стоит - 12. какая у вас? а что сообщило: "Ошибка преобразования значения varchar "БУЗОО "КОБ ИМ. В.П. ВЫХОДЦЕВА"" в тип данных int."

Comment: а вы его в чем писали ? именно в pivot не проверял никогда. в обычных запросах типа `select max(nam_mok) from tab`  работает в любых СУБД, любых версий

Comment: @Mike не тут то да, сработает при обычном select, а когда я делаю pivot то те значения которые он переворачивает нужны именно в числовом виде как я понял.

Comment: Странно, вбил в гугле "ms-sql string pivot" там по всем ссылкам примеры и судя по всему отлично работающие... и они все с max

Comment: @Mike действительно очень странно

Comment: ну если ничего не помогает, то ручной pivot, старым проверенным способом: `select max(case when column_mo='mo1' then nam_mok end) as mo1, ... from tab group by (если нужен)`

Comment: @Mike ну ручной pivot не подходит так как задел был именно на изменение числа колонок :( ладно попробуем так: закину результат с кодом во временную, изменю ей тип полей и обновлю строки

Comment: А какая разница, обычный pivot то же число колонок менять не умеет. ему все равно надо перечислять все ожидаемые значения.

Comment: @Mike нашел в интернете генерируемый pivot, ему нужно только указать колонки откуда брать имена новых колонок, что переворачивать, как группировать и какую функцию использовать, и если колонки меняются то уже не надо переписывать всё, просто учитываю это в отчете на конце всего этого "костыля"

Comment: Ну такому скрипту в общем то все равно что генерить, запрос с pivot или с max(case). хотя pivot конечно немного лаконичнее и проще делать

Comment: @Mike так вот бред и в том что такой скрипт с функцией max у меня не работает( [как здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319562/sql-pivot-with-string)

Comment: Я там скрипта не вижу, там только текст самого запроса, который собственно скрипт и должен создавать. Может ошибка с max и строкой как раз в скрипте

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все что требуется это получить список из колонки `[column_mo]` и просунуть его в динамический `PIVOT`:

```
--Заберем нужную информацию во временную таблицу
SELECT nam_mok,column_mo INTO #INFO FROM #listmo

--Добавим заголовок
ALTER TABLE #INFO ADD [Header] nvarchar(250)
--Заполним заголовок
UPDATE #INFO SET [Header] = N'Мед. организация'  

--Переменные для динамического SQL, и списка
Declare @Columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@SQL  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

--Список внутри [column_mo]
SET @Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + column_mo 
                    From  #INFO
                   For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

--Динамический PIVOT
Set @SQL = 'Select [Header],'+ @Columns +' From #INFO
            Pivot (
                   max(nam_mok)
                   For [column_mo] in (' + @Columns + ')
                  ) p '

--его выполнение
exec sp_executesql @SQL

DROP TABLE #listmo,#INFO;
```

Будьте внимательны, в конце я дропаю и вашу временную таблицу **тоже**.

Подробнее:
[использование PIVOT и UNPIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)
[dynamic PIVOT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/)

Comment: странно, на этом варианте работает, спасибо