# Как создать виртуальную таблицу (view) для EAV?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, eav

Имеются три, типичные для [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), таблицы:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EntityTypes (
  Id [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  EntityName [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE EntityAttributes (
  Id [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  EntityTypeId [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  AttributeName [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE AttributeValues (
  Id [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  EntityAttributeId [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  AttributeValue [nvarchar](max) NULL,
);
```

Таблица `AttributeValues` ссылается на `EntityAttributes`, которая, в свою очередь, ссылается на `EntityTypes`. С приведённой схемой, пользователь может создать новый тип сущности, указать для него произвольное количество свойств/атрибутов и сохранить значения этих атрибутов.

Можно ли создать для этих таблиц либо виртуальную таблицу (view), либо если это невозможно, то SQL запрос, который бы содержал имена атрибутов (`EntityAttributes.AttributeName`) в качестве столбцов? Вроде как для этих целей можно использовать [PIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot), но насколько я понял в этом случае необходимо знать значения "поворачиваемых" столбцов, а имена столбцов, в моем случае, неизвестны.

Comment: В SQL _всегда_ структура возвращаемой "таблицы" должна быть известна заранее. И зависит это не от синтаксиса (pivot или что угодно другое), а от базовых принципов SQL как такового. разворачивание структуры в горизонтальную надо производить либо на клиенте, либо создавать запрос с нужной структурой динамически

Comment: `либо создавать запрос с нужной структурой динамически` как бы в этом и вопрос...

Comment: "динамически" в view не засунешь. Ибо view это та же "таблица". Вот например как делать динамически на чистом ms-sql https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941806/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-pivot

Comment: А вообще подозреваю что на это счет должны быть какие то готовые решения для c#, раз о нем речь

Comment: В теории EAV выглядит здорово. Но EAV как раз за то и критикуют, что на практике с этой моделью работать тяжело.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не спорю, но без неё никак, т.к. на день по нескольку раз переписывать программу - это тоже жесть.

Comment: Может вас заинтересует: обсуждение [расширенной](https://www.sql.ru/forum/1315355/kak-nazvat-etu-strukturu-i-podhod-osnovannye-na-eav) модели EAV, [квинтетная](https://habr.com/ru/post/465161/) модель данных (и по ссылкам смотрите предыдущие статьи). Выглядит, по крайней мере, интересно.